# how to tell if user caused selectedindexchanged

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a SelectedIndexChanged event firing when the index in a combobox changes.

I call this from code in a timer,
and the user calls it when they select an option.

I cannot figure out how to tell if it was a user action that caused this event to fire or some other event.

I have tried a flag in my timer, which does work but i was looking for a more open solution, that would be more future proof.

Comment: better you show code that you have ..

Comment: yes, code please - need to understand how you fire this event by the timer: would you change the selection index to trigger the event or straightaway call the event handler method?

Comment: From what you say (as requested by the comments above: code, please!!) what you are doing is the best proceeding. No internal property of the combobox (or any other control) can tell who used it (user or code at runtime); you have to be the one performing this differentiation, for example, via logical flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this by adding event selectionchangecommitted

```
Private Sub cboGraphType_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboGraphType.SelectionChangeCommitted
    startStopTimer(True)
End Sub
```

this then stops the timer, and then the selectionchanged event still fires after this.

but this event stop my timer, which is what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

About use any flag ...

```
Dim ByWhat As String 

Private Sub timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles timer1.Tick
    ByWhat = "TIMER1"
    MyJob()       
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    ByWhat = "COMBOBOX1"
    MyJob()

End Sub

Sub MyJob()

  Select Case ByWhat
  Case "TIMER1"
    'code if called by timer1

  Case "COMBOBOX1"
    'code if called by combobox1

  End Select 

  ByWhat = "" '---->Clear it
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this, it doesnt work, as the selectedIndexChanged can be on a different thread to the the tick event.